# Recording audio from one multi-channel interface vs multiple single-channel interfaces

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I've decided it's time I started recording some of my music. So I've bought a couple of Samson Meteor USB microphones. They're quite nice and works out of the box. I'll use one to mic up my guitar amplifier and the other will be used for voice. I've chosen this way of doing it because it will enable me some more flexibility later, but it also means some added complexity. And since I'm really quite inexperienced with audio recordings, I could use some advise.

To my knowledge, Audacity can only record from one audio interface at a time, though it can handle multiple channels from a single audio interface. Since I do have some experience using Audacity, it would be nice if I could continue to use it somehow. In the back of my mind, I remember seeing that you can create virtual audio interfaces in PulseAudio. Would that be a viable solution in this case?

Also, should I expect any noticeable differences in performance when using multiple single-channel interfaces rather than one multi-channel interface, such as much added latency?

In general; are there things I should be aware of, that I'm not experienced enough to ask about?